# Unusual request activity log found in django server

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

Following is the screenshot of the server activity log.I can see that many requests are automatically raised in the server.How can I avoid this.? [image]

[image]

Comment: Someone is scanning your website for vulnerabilities

Comment: @IainShelvington how can I avoid this.?

Comment: Is it affecting the performance of your site? If not, then there is not much benefit in buying/implementing a solution. Several companies offer solutions that protect you from DoS and DDoS attacks, but unless you are making money off the site there is not much point (a quick google has turned up hSo and AWS Shield)

Comment: @IainShelvington Currently no such performance issue till date. Is there any way to log the IP address of such requests into a file in django .?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like someone is fuzzing your website and scanning to find any common file names or extensions that commonly have security vulnerabilities. One way to limit this behaviour is to implement [rate limiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_limiting) whereby you might limit the number of requests a user makes that result in `HTTP 404 Not Found` during some time period before giving them a temporary ban. *Note: this solution doesn't stop this from happening but it does buy you time and may deter the attacker or researcher*